# MatLab strcat and fprintf function

Tags: matlab, printf

I am trying to send a string of characters over serial using the fprintf function.

I am executing this within a MatLab GUIDE callback function

For some reason, fprintf does not consider the variable I pass over to it as a string, although it was treated as such in the disp() funciton call just one line above. I would like to understand why that is and what I should change.

I get an error from MatLab:

```
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

calibration button hit
    10

   200

30
100
        1260

       25197

1260
25197
    'C0 1260 25197 30 100'

Error using serial/fprintf (line 84)
The third input argument must be a string.

Error in UserInterface>StaticCalibrationBtn_Callback (line 202)
fprintf(handles.s, '%s', OutputString);
```

Here is the code sample that is causing the problem

```
function StaticCalibrationBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to StaticCalibrationBtn (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
disp('calibration button hit');
Start = str2double(get(handles.CalFromUserTxt, 'string')); % Fetches the user inputed start location in mm and converts to double
disp(Start);
End = str2double(get(handles.CalToUserTxt, 'string')); % same for End position
disp(End);
Increment = get(handles.CalUserIncrementTxt, 'string'); % fetches the increment user inputed data as a string
disp(Increment);
Wait = get(handles.CalUserSpeedTxt, 'string'); % fetches the wait inputed data as a string
disp(Wait);
StartSteps = round(Start/0.00793750000); % computes the starting step position,double division
disp(StartSteps);
handles.StartSteps = StartSteps; % creats a place for the start steps inside the handles structure, to be fetched by anythingelsest be saved with guidata(hObject,handles)
EndSteps = round(End/0.00793750000); % computes the end step position
disp(EndSteps);
handles.EndSteps = EndSteps; % stores the end steps to be accessed by anything else must be saved with guidata(hObject,handles)
StartStepsStr = num2str(StartSteps); % converts the StartSteps double into a string so it can be sent over serial as a string
disp(StartStepsStr);
EndStepsStr = num2str(EndSteps); % converts the EndSteps double into a string so it can be sent over serial as a string
disp(EndStepsStr);
OutputString = strcat('C0' , {' '} , StartStepsStr , {' '} , EndStepsStr , {' '} , Increment , {' '} , Wait);
disp(OutputString);
fprintf(handles.s, '%s', OutputString);
```

The fprintf call causing a problem is at the bottom of the code snipet.
serial communication was established successfully before the call.

---

Additional details about handles.s

It is an object containing the serial port information. It is stored in another callback. See below

```
function SerialBtn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to SerialBtn (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA
comPort = get(handles.COMportTxt,'String');
if(~exist('serialFlag','var'))
    [handles.s, handles.serialFlag] = setupSerial(comPort);
end
guidata(hObject,handles);
end
```

The function itself is described below

```
function [ s, flag] = setupSerial(comPort)
%Initialize serial port communication between Arduino and Matlab
%Ensure that the arduino is also communicating with Matlab at this time. 
%if setup is complete then the value of setup is returned as 1 else 0.

flag =1;
s = serial(comPort);
set(s,'DataBits',8);
set(s,'StopBits',1);
set(s,'BaudRate',9600);
set(s,'Parity','none');
fopen(s);
a='b';
while (a~='a')
    a=fread(s,1,'uchar');
end
if (a=='a')
    disp('serial read');
end
fprintf(s,'%c','a');
mbox = msgbox('Serial Communication setup.'); uiwait(mbox);
fscanf(s,'%u');
```

### end

EDIT : it was pointed out that the `strcat` function outputs an Array of string rather then a string, which is not compatible with fprintf. The question then is:

How can `strcat` be used to generate a string with spaces that would be compatible with the fprintf function?

EDIT 2:
The following

```
space = ' ';
OutputString = strcat('C0' , space , StartStepsStr , space , EndStepsStr , space , Increment , space , Wait);
```

Outputs the following, with no `''` around...so we're slowly getting there.

```
C01260251972020
```

Comment: What is `handles.s`?

Comment: I have edited my question with a detailed answer to your question. Thanks for your comment

Comment: From the [`strcat`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) documentation: _If **any** input argument is a cell array, the result is a **cell array** of strings. Otherwise, the result is a character array._ And you can see in your `disp` output that the string is enclosed by `'`. This is not a good sign. `disp` can deal with cell array ... but not `fprintf`. So check the type of your variable in the workspace when you get errors like this, the answer is often in your workspace ;-)

Comment: Thanks. That is probably what causes the error. I can't get the variable type to output though. From the documentation, I read that whos(variable) should output the properties but that doesnt work for me. Everything is handled within a GUIDE gui. Is there another way to check the type of a variable?

Comment: Try the `class` function for determining a variable type.